# ¿Cómo insertar datos en una tabla de MySQLi mediante un <Option value> en PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<td> <select style="width:95%; border-radius:5px" required pattern="\w+" type="text" name="tip" id="tip">
    <option value="Profesor">Profesor</option>
    <option value="Estudiante">Estudiante</option>
    <option value="Administrador">Administrador</option>

    <?php
    if ((option value=="Estudiante")) {

        $sql3="INSERT INTO estudiantes (ced_usu,est_est,cod_cur) VALUES ('".$ced."','','')"; 
    }       
    ?>
```

Comment: Te comento lo mismo que en la otra pregunta (¿que borraste?): ese código puede sufrir ataques de inyección SQL, deberías dejar de usar consultas dinámicas y empezar a utilizar consultas preparadas/parametrizadas

Comment: esta bien, gracias por el comentario, indagare sobre eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente comprueba el valor `$_POST['tip']`

```
if ($_POST['tip'] =="Estudiante") {

   $sql3 = "INSERT INTO estudiantes (ced_usu,est_est,cod_cur) VALUES ('".$ced."','','')";

}
```

**NOTA IMPORTANTE:**

Por favor usa sentencias preparada de [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) o mejor aún, usa la interfaz de [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/class.pdo.php), para evitar cualquier ataque ante una [Inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

Comment: gracias @aldanux, todavía no esta insertando en la segunda tabla pero ya estoy acercándome , no me aparece ningún error